# Getting Bad file descriptor everytime I install something using brew

Tags: macos, certificate

Why am I always getting bad file descriptor error, everytime I try to install any application using homebrew

Error Logs:-

```
Error: Failure while executing; `cp -pR /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/. /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates` exited with 1. Here's the output:
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/.: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/.: Bad file descriptor
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: Permission denied
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew/ca-certificates.rb: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/.brew: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: unable to copy extended attributes to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share/ca-certificates: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01/share: No such file or directory
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: No such file or directory
cp: chown: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: No such file or directory
cp: chmod: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: No such file or directory
cp: chflags: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: No such file or directory
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/./2022-02-01: Permission denied
cp: setattrlist: /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/.: Permission denied
cp: /private/tmp/d20220226-3322-2zsx5k/ca-certificates/.: unable to copy ACL to /usr/local/Cellar/ca-certificates/.: Bad file descriptor
```

I tried to update and upgrade brew, but getting same error of Bad File Descriptor

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R ${USER}:staff /usr/local/Cellar/
```

Fixed for me

Comment: I'm not sure if it's because of different macOS versions, but I had to fix access rights for another path (I had an issue with `fastlane` upgrade):

```sh
sudo chown -R ${USER}:staff /opt/homebrew/Cellar/
```